# Class '\Omnipay\FirstData\Gateway' not found Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, omnipay, firstdata, payeezy

The error is:

> Class '\Omnipay\FirstData\Gateway' not found

after request Omnipay in laravel php project.

Comment: You need to install your composer dependencies before using them.

Comment: We'll need more information for this to be answerable. Did you attempt to install this project via composer? Did you invoke the composer's autoloader (Laravel probably does this for you)? Please the steps you took to install the package, and some code that demonstrates the issue